# c++ конкатенация (объединение) 2х векторов

Tags: c++, vector, объединение, move

Какой самый быстрый способ объединения 2х векторов (`std::vector`)? Т.е. присоединить вектор 2 к вектору 1. Нужен вариант как с `move` семантикой, чтобы вектор 2 был пустым, так и с копированием (наиболее быстрым), и еще для POD типов (опять таки быстрый).
Ну и как дополнение к вопросу: а если нужно соединить более 2х векторов?

Comment: 1. Всё тут: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy. 2.  Последовательно.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy

Comment: Для POD просто расширяете целевой вектор и делаете `memmove`. В любом случае лучше O(n) не получится из-за обязательного переноса объектов в памяти, так что мне представляется, что `resize` + `emplace_back`/`push_back` (возможно, с `move`) будет максимально быстрым вариантом... При `copy` выполняется то же самое поэлементное копирование, разве что теоретически параллелизуемое, ну и лучше при больших размерах `copy` не через `back_inserter`, а с предварительным `resize`.

Comment: Может, лучше заменить `vector` на `list`?

Comment: @Harry Т.е. остается только поэлементное копирование вручную или с помощью `copy` ? А еще же `memove` не получится просто так применить к содержимому 2го вектора?

Comment: Похоже на то. Что до `memmove` — прочтите еще раз, что я написал: ***Для POD** просто расширяете целевой вектор и делаете `memmove`*, особенно обратив внимание на выделенную часть... POD — [plain old data](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85), никаких классов/конструкторов/деструкторов, никаких указателей...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ниже функция которая переносит элементы вектора `b` в конец вектора `a`. Если вы хотите использовать её много раз с одним и тем же вектором `a`, рекомендую вызвать `a.reserve()` с размером равным длине ожидаемого результата.

Если вы не хотите разрушать элементы `b`, уберите вызовы `std::make_move_iterator`.

```
template<typename Item>
void concat(std::vector<Item> &a, std::vector<Item> &b) {
    a.insert(
        a.end(),
        std::make_move_iterator(b.begin()),
        std::make_move_iterator(b.end())
    );
}
```

Этот код работает одинаково хорошо и для POD и для сложных типов с конструкторами. Например берём код

```
struct S { int i; };

void concat(std::vector<S> &a, std::vector<S> &b) {
    a.insert(
        a.end(),
        std::make_move_iterator(b.begin()),
        std::make_move_iterator(b.end())
    );
}
```

Компилируем его с оптимизацией в ассемблер: `g++ -S -O3 concat.cpp`. В файле `concat.s` можно найти код в котором в основной ветке, когда места в векторе `a` достаточно, вызывается `call memmove` один раз. Если места недостаточно, то в коде выделяется новая память и делаются два вызова `call memcpy` (старые данные `a`) и `call memove` (новые данные из `b`). Циклов нигде нет, всё настолько оптимально насколько возможно.

Если тип имеет нетривиальный конструктор, без циклов не обойдётся. Но тут уж ничего не поделаешь.